# How to reduce 28 V to 24 V under load?

Tags: power, voltage, pwm

I need to PWM control six **24 V** DC fans with a total load of 10.6 amperes. That's easy, right? Just PWM to a few MOSFETs. However, my system voltage is **28 V**.  At 28 V I'm out of specification for the fans and looking at a 36% increase in power (watts). I'm guessing I probably don't want to PWM the raw 28 V to the fans, right?

I'm in a power-draw sensitive scenario, so I don't want to just stick some big power resistors in line to reduce the voltage to them. I've also looked into RC low pass filters to smooth the PWM voltage to be within specification for the fans, but I'd need a very small resistor and basically a bank of 10 µF ceramic capacitors.

What is a good solution in this scenario? Is there one?

Comment: Can you please explain the statement " ...At 28 V I'm out of specification for the fans ..." -> Do you mean that 28V is above the fan voltage rating or that the power consumption at 28V is above what you can tolerate or ...?

Comment: What technology does the fan use? -> Brushed motor, Brushless DC,... ? | If you PWM the fan at 24/28th duty cycle = 85.7% on, and 28V in, at PWM frame rates of eg 100 / 1000 / 10000 ... Hz with no smoothing will the fan controller act as if it "sees" 24V  or pulsed 28V. | Have you measured fan current at eg 22 24 26 28 V? | Do you understand my arguments below re relative consumption at 28V and 24V and how a resistor MAY be almost as good as alternatives.

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Comment: I'm running them in series of two. The voltage spec is 7.0-13.2v, power max 28.2W.  They are single phase, four pole brushless fans.  I have not measured fan current at PWM'd values or alternate voltages yet.  I do totally understand that the benefit of a buck converter may only be marginally better than a straight resistive drop.

Comment: The statement they draw 36% more power at 28V is assumed based on simple resistive calculations, not measured calculations.  One thought I had is that with the voltage spec max at 13.2v, I can likely get away with a series resistor to drop the voltage just a bit.  They will be at the higher end of the voltage range but within spec and will be PWM'd anyhow...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't easily test the 26v/28v characteristics at the moment as I only have a 24v power supply (28v is on order).

Answer (score 8):

Added:

This is an intriguing problem BECAUSE it is a relatively simple one once all the facts are known BUT the more you look, the more you see that not all potentially relevant facts are yet known. I'm not going to dive down all the rabbit holes at this stage as Ray can easily add the additional information if he wishes and I'll wait until he does. But, here is what a few of the burrow entrances look like.

Ray said " ... At 28 V I'm out of specification for the fans ...".
That could mean that the voltage is too high or that they draw too much power there or ...
Which it is matters.

Ray said that the fans draw 36% more power at 28V compared to 24V. This would be true of a resistor (as P = V^2/R)_ but is less like;y to be true of a fan, but may be. Was this measured or assumed?

Ray stated that Itotal is 10.6 A at 24V and that was acceptable. How much lower is it as eg 22V and is the airflow then still acceptable.

PWM with out filtering at 85.7% duty cycle (call it 86%) and 26V in, yields effectively 24V mean out.

PWM with no filtering imposes 28V pulses and 0-V "pulses" on the motor. This MAY cause the fans to draw pulses of current as if they had 28V applied for 86% of the time so Ifan average may be higher than if 24V DC was applied. This depends on the fan technology and other factors.

Some fans will be happy with PWM applied - although many would "like" an inverse flywheel diode. Some fans will go berserk with PWM applied and with some it may depend on PWM frequency.

If you filter PWM with and RC filter to make smoothish DC then you will lose power in the filter R as if it was a pure R dropper. The apparent R value is simply multiplied by R/Duty_cycle (as long as there are no PWM related second order effects).

If you filter with and LC filter you need an input flywheel diode for when PWM is off and you have a buck converter. This can work well but efficiency may be less improved over a straight dropper R than may be expected.

IF ... more rabbit holes ....

So:

- What does " ...At 28 V I'm out of specification for the fans ..." mean?
- What technology does the fan use? -> Brushed motor, Brushless DC,... ?
- If you PWM the fan at 24/28th duty cycle = 85.7% on, and 28V in, at PWM frame rates of eg 100 / 1000 / 10000 ... Hz with no smoothing will the fan controller act as if it "sees" 24V or pulsed 28V?
- What is the MEASURED fan current at eg 22 24 26 28 V?
  What are the measured currents.
- Is air flow at 22 VDC at fan acceptable?

**Given**  Ifan at 24V = 10.6A = "I24", Vin = 28V.

Wattage with dropper resistor = 28 x I24

Wattage with 90% efficient buck converter = 24 x I24 / 0.90 = 26.7 x I24

Wattage with 95% efficient buck converter = 24 x I24 / 0.95 = 25.3 x I24

Gains are shown in the table below. To get the power reduction of probably around 5% requires provision of a 20A+ , 30V+ rated switch a PWM source a 12A capable inductor, 10A diode, and output capacitor   OR a 100 Watt rated (ideally) resistor. The table shows the various relevant losses and gains. Whether the cost and effort is worth implementing a 90% efficient buck converter or trying even harder for a 95% buck converter is up to Ray to decide.

[image]

---

Original - still relevant:

You say that 28V operation requires 36% more energy than 24V.
That would be true with a purely resistive load as \$power = V^2/R\$ so increases with voltage\$^2\$ and \$(28/24)^2 = 1.36\$. Depending on fan technology this may not be true - as fan motor back emf increases with velocity.

However, if this is true then reducing fan voltage to 24V will reduce current and power so if you then resistively drop voltage from 28V you are still better off than using 28V on the fan directly.

---

If you PWM the fan directly it needs to be able to tolerate the 28V peaks and the technology used needs to be "happy" with the PWM modulation. If you smooth the PWM with an RC filter you lose about the same power as if you used a resistive dropper. ie completely smooth (impossible) is same power loss as a pure resistor and minimal smoothing = no resistive losses BUT motor characteristics will affect how the fan power changes.

Adding a series L that does not saturate and a 'flyback' diode after the PWM switch effectively yields a buck converter.

Note that a linear regulator or voltage dropper will have an efficiency of 24V/28V = 85.7%
While you can get better than that with a buck converter you need to decide if the gain is worthwhile.

At 90% you'd get 90/85.7 = 5.02% more run time per energy used.
At 95% you'd get 95/85.7 = 10.9% more run time per energy used.

24v x 10.6A = 254 Watts
28V x 10.6A = 296.8 Watts
The energy lost in a purely resistive dropper is 42.8 Watts = 14.42% (as you'd expect) of a total of 297W.

Using a buck converter you are unlikely to save more than perhaps another 20 Watts - halving losses to around 20 Watts.  Even with an exceptionally good converter you'd probably only an an extra 10 Watt's savings.

It's quite likely that a resistive dropper is good enough.

If you can run the fan on say 22V you may dissipate more power in the dropper but use less energy overall. A good knowledge of fan Voltage/current/airflow characteristics and actual needs will help optimisation.

Answer (score 6):

Two easy solutions.

1. A suitable buck converter. Your probably looking at 90% efficiency.
2. PWM. Adjust your PWM so that your maximum rate is 85% instead of 100%. This will result in an average of 23.8V (plus the mosfets drop) in your PWM period.

Comment: I am also guessing that he has some sort of feedback (RPM or voltage) so the second solution would be super easy. You just lose some precision but with a 16 bit pwm you still have some 55k steps.

Comment: 2. is potentially problematic. With no filtering you are applying 28V pulses to the motor which his "out of specification" MAY mean is excessive. And if it's a BLDCM then PWM may annoy the controller. Or not. I you fully smooth the PWM with RC filtering you get the same efficiency as a dropper resistor :-(. If you get 90% with a buck converter then power in is 24 x 10.6/ 0.90 = 283 Watts. If you use a linear dropper 28 x 10.6 = 297 Watts. So 90% PWM uses 283/297 = 95% of the energy and takes 14 Watts off 297. MAY be worthwhile, but maybe not.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I inferred his concern is total power. 28V is a 12% increase in voltage over the nominal 24V, I don't expect a fan to be so marginal to its max power input.

Answer (score 5):

PWM control of a Buck Power Stage with feedforward duty cycle (i.e. no feedback), could be an option. (picture source [eetimes](http://www.automotive-eetimes.com/en/cranking-simulator-made-easy.html?cmp_id=71&news_id=222903405))

Just set the duty cycle to 24/28/0.9 = 0.95  and the output will be ~24V for 28V in.

It's completely unregulated because there's no feedback, but for a fan it should work. You may want to pay attention at turn-on to ramping up the duty cycle from 0% to 95% to prevent inrush currents.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My company makes DC fan speed controllers for very large earth-moving equipment.  Each fan draws 6 - 7A @ 24Vdc and there are 10 fans in the system.  Two fans per power stage, 5 power stages in the box.

The client company has used several different brands of DC fans over the years and they all respond nicely to PWM.  Because we are concerned with not interfering with their radio communications, we have a large LC filter at the output of each of the PWM stages.  That does make the PWM stage into a buck converter for the units that we build.  Nonetheless, the fans work very well without the LC filter.

Another poster mentioned ramping the duty-cycle slowly on startup.  That turned out to be important in our application.  Luckily, PWM control makes this easy.